# Variable not declared in the scope error

Tags: c++, variables, arduino, declaration

[image: Image about the error]

Why am I getting this problem and how can I fix it? From my point of view I already declared it. Please see the image.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It would be better to post the code in your question, instead of an image of code

Answer (score 3):

You have an extra semicolon between the `for` statement and opening brace. That makes the `for` loop have an empty body, and the braced expressions have no idea what `angle` is supposed to be, since it truly is out-of-scope.

Comment: You are right!
Thanks a lot!